# Phone manager/Battery optimizer app kills foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, locationmanager, foreground-service

-I am developing an application that records user location in a .csv file and uploads them to firebase storage and I've written a service to accomplish this. The service needs to run indefinitely until the user stops it (by unchecking a switch from the activity that launched the service). The service runs in foreground and after running for 15-20 minutes, the phone manager app gives "resource intensive app found" notification and kills the service. onDestroy() never gets called!. I return START_STICKY which is supposed to recreate the service and call onStartCommand() again but the service never gets created again!

I've seen some people write workarounds for this problem but they target specific android versions. My app targets android Pie and I haven't seen any "generic" solution to this problem yet. All solutions are either device/brand specific or API level specific. For now I'm testing the app on Huawei Y7 prime 2018 (Android O) and on my device, i got around this by manually disallowing the phone manager app to manage my application, this way the service does run indefinitely until the user kills it from the app. The nature of the application is such that i need minimum user engagement and i don't expect the users to go through the hassle of manually disabling my app from battery optimizer/phone manager app. My LocationService.java class is attached, if somebody could please provide either a better implementation of this service or some generic method to keep it alive, that'd be great. Even some hack to make sure that onDestroy() gets called before the system kills the application would work!

```
package com.example.bumps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "LocationServiceChannel";
    private static final int ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static final String PREFS_TAG = "PendingUploadPrefs";

    private LocationManager locationManager;


    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
    DecimalFormat coordinatesFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00000");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfForDir = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss");


    File locationDirectory;
    String currentDataDirectory;
    FirebaseStorage filesStorage;

    String userUUID;
    List<ResumeFileUpload> pendingFileUploads;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor;
    private SOTWFormatter sotwFormatter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        filesStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        pendingFileUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPrefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        sotwFormatter = new SOTWFormatter(this);

        String timeStamp = sdfForDir.format(new Date());
        currentDataDirectory = "RBD_" + timeStamp;
        locationDirectory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), currentDataDirectory);
        if (!locationDirectory.exists())
            locationDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //userUUID = intent.getStringExtra("userUUID");
        userUUID = sharedPreferences.getString("userUUID", "UNKNOWN");

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    0, 0, this);
        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        createNotificationChannel();
        Notification notification =
                new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
                        .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bump)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
                        .build();

        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Location Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            try {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }

        File newFileLoc  = writeLocationDataToFile(locationStringBuilder);
        pendingFileUploads.add(new ResumeFileUpload(currentDataDirectory,
                newFileLoc.getPath()));
        uploadToStorage(newFileLoc);


        /*if there are no pending files from some previous session, just save the ones
        * that just got created*/
        if (getPendingFileUploads() == null){
            setList("PendingUploads", pendingFileUploads);
        }else{
            /*if there are pending uploads from some previous session, fetch them,
            * update the list of pending uploads with and save for later upload*/
            List<ResumeFileUpload> pUploads = getPendingFileUploads();
            for (ResumeFileUpload resumeFileUpload: pendingFileUploads){
                pUploads.add(resumeFileUpload);
            }
            setList("PendingUploads", pUploads);
        }
    }

    private List<ResumeFileUpload> getPendingFileUploads(){
        List<ResumeFileUpload> pendingUploads = null;
        String serializedObject = sharedPreferences.getString("PendingUploads", null);
        if (serializedObject != null){
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<ResumeFileUpload>>(){}.getType();
            pendingUploads = gson.fromJson(serializedObject, type);
        }
        return pendingUploads;
    }

    private boolean deleteFile(File file){
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            File fdelete = new File(uri.getPath());
            if (fdelete.exists()) {
                if (fdelete.delete()) {
                    System.out.println("file Deleted :" + uri.getPath());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + uri.getPath());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private File writeLocationDataToFile(StringBuilder data) {
        String fileName = "Location.csv";
        String colNamesLoc = "Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,Accuracy,DirectionOfMotion,Speed\n";
        File newFile = new File(locationDirectory, fileName);
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);

            fileWriter.append(colNamesLoc);

            fileWriter.append(data.toString());
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved To " + getExternalFilesDir(null)
                    + "/" + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newFile;
    }

    private void uploadToStorage(final File newFile){

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(newFile.getPath()));
        StorageReference storageReference = filesStorage.getReference()
                .child(userUUID + "/" + currentDataDirectory + "/" +
                        uri.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(uri);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(LocationService.this,
                        newFile.getName() + " Upload Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                deleteFile(newFile);
                Toast.makeText(LocationService.this,
                        newFile.getName() + " Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    /*Location Listener*/

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            String lat = coordinatesFormat.format(location.getLatitude());
            String lng = coordinatesFormat.format(location.getLongitude());
            String bearing = "0.0";
            if (location.getBearing() != 0.0)
                bearing = String.valueOf(sotwFormatter.format(location.getBearing()));

            int speed = (int) location.getSpeed();
            String currentSpeed = String.valueOf(speed * 3.6f) + " KM/h";
            String accuracy = "0.0";
            if (location.getAccuracy() != 0.0)
                accuracy = coordinatesFormat.format(location.getAccuracy());

            String timeStamp = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            String locationData = timeStamp + ", " + lat +
                    ", " + lng + ", " + accuracy + ", " + bearing + ", "
                    + currentSpeed;
            locationStringBuilder.append(locationData);
            locationStringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    /*SharedPreferences code*/

    public <T> void setList(String key, List<T> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);

        set(key, json);
    }

    public void set(String key, String value) {
        sharedPrefEditor.putString(key, value);
        sharedPrefEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set a timer and refresh the service by calling stopSelf() and then call startService() in onDestroy().

Comment: @KarthikPai thank you for the response. Could you be e little more specific about where should i set the timer exactly? and as i mentioned, onDestroy() never gets called! the system just brutally kills the application.

Comment: See also [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com/)

Comment: Set timer immediately after you start your service. When the specific duration ends, call stopSelf(). onDestroy() method will definitely get called when your service ends because of call to stopSelf() or stopService(). Then in onDestroy(), call startService() again. When system kills your app, onDestroy() will not get called.

Comment: Should an `onDestroy` method really start a `UploadTask`? That doesn't seem like the purpose of an `onDestroy` to me.